# ADTs and values

Tags: casting, rascal

In Rascal, say I have the code:

```
value x = 2;
data Exp = con(int n);
```

Is there a way to call con(x), while x is a value (but actually an integer), without knowing on beforehand what the type of con's first argument is supposed to be (thus without explicitly casting it to an int)?

Why is it possible to call a function, say int something(int n) = n, with an integer defined as a value (e.g. value y = 2) passed into its first argument, while it gives me an error when I try to do the same with user-defined ADTs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call a function in Rascal it actually is doing a pattern match on the arguments. So, if you define `int something(int n) = n;`, and then call `something(x)`, it matches `x` with `int n`, sees that `x` is actually an `int` (so it can bind the value to `n`), and calls the function.

If you were to define `value x = 2.5` instead and then call `something(x)` you would get an error since it cannot bind the value `2.5` to `int n`. You could overload `something` with a second definition that takes a real instead, like `int something(real r) = toInt(r);`, and it would then work. Two items to note here, though: `something` needs to return the same type in both cases, and you need to import `util::Math` to get access to `toInt`.

When you are using a constructor, like `con(x)`, it doesn't do a pattern match for you automatically. The type that you give it has to match the type it expects. If you know that `x` will always be an `int`, it would be best to just declare it as such. Another option would be to create a function like `Exp makeCon(int n) = con(n);` which you could then use as you would like, i.e., `Exp myExp = makeCon(x);`. It would be best in this case to include a default version of the function, just in case you give it something unexpected, like `default Exp makeCon(value x) { throw "Unexpected value <x>"; }`, this way if you ever try to create a `con` with something that isn't an `int` you will get an error that you can handle, with the ability to create your own error message, add additional error handling versus just showing a message, see the value causing the problem, etc, versus just having the interpreter give an error (which may not give you all the info you want).

Comment: As to the "why" question; we try to warn the programmer if a run-time error could occur. Run-time errors like "constructor or function not defined" are avoided due to this behavior. Mark explains well how you can add an alternative function definition to allow calling the constructor with any value. I'd write `Exp con(value x) { throw "argument is not an int"; }`